# Can you identify the large transparent windows in this Ideas submission?

Tags: part-identification, ideas

Can anyone identify the large curved transparent windows in [this aviary build](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/ec65cf45-95e9-415f-b398-a75f8133c909/official_comments#content_nav_tabs)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is [Panel 6 x 6 x 9 Curved Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2572#T=C).

[image: Panel 6 x 6 x 9 Curved Top]

I couldn't find the other one that's containing the brown parrots, however.

Correct me if I'm wrong, because there were a few other parts like this which were almost identical.

Answer (score 4):

The other transparent part is

[Cylinder Quarter 4 x 4 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30562&idColor=12#T=C&C=12)

[image]